# how to have powershell script search through directories along with root directory

Tags: powershell

```
cd ("F:\Offcloud\Gossip Girl\Season 01")
Dir | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace "%20","" }
Dir | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace "%27","" }
Dir | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace "a","" }
Dir | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace "b","" }
Dir | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace "c","" }
Dir | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace "d","" }
Dir | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace "e","" }
Dir | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace "f","" }
Dir | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace "g","" }
```

Etc.. basically, I want to remove everything except a small list (0123456789x). Is there any way I can do this? My current script is taking a very LONG time.  Also, how can I change my script to also go through all children directories?

Comment: Explain `"remove everything except a small list"`. What do you want to do? Or do you want the same behavior, just written in a shorter way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `-Recurse` parameter to search down directory levels.

```
$SearchFolder = "F:\Offcloud\Gossip Girl\Season 01"
Get-ChildItem -Path $SearchFolder -Recurse `
    | Rename-Item -NewName { 
        ($_.BaseName -replace "%20|%27|a|b|c|d|e|f|g","") + $_.Extension 
    }
```

Then if you use the `regex`'s OR operator (`|`) in your `-replace` string you can replace all strings at once. The replace is done on the `BaseName` which is the file name without the extension. Then we simply add the extension onto the end.

Comment: thanks.. one more issue, is there anyway I can get it to not remove file extension? Say, the last 4 characters?

Comment: Thanks.  had to break it up into multiple scripts though, it only checks the 10 or so ors..

Answer (score 0):

use this command :

```
$path = "F:\Offcloud\Gossip Girl\Season 01"

dir $path -Recurse -Include * |Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace "%20|%27|a|b|c|d|e|f|g|h","" }
```